# Unable to locate package apache2-bin

Tags: apt, apache2

I tried to run

```
apache2
```

And it said

```
Command 'apache2' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install apache2-bin
```

So I ran

```
apt install apache2-bin
```

And it said

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2-bin
```

I tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` and it still didn't work.

I'm running Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-aarch64-2022.11.06-0

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: try `sudo apt add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: @OrganicMarble Done

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does this mean "Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-aarch64-2022.11.06-0" Are you running on a Pi or something like that, not an Intel or AMD architecture?

Comment: I'm running an oracle cloud virtual machine with the image set to Canonical Ubuntu 22.04. The CPU is an arm-based processor

Comment: Did you do the `apt install apache2-bin` *after* the `apt update`? This is important.

Comment: @popey Yes I did, and I still get the "Unable to locate package apache2-bin" error

Comment: Shouldn't they be using `ports.ubuntu.com` rather than `archive.ubuntu.com` for ARM? Does it find *any* packages for your architecture?

Comment: Well spotted @steeldriver - the sources.list file is wrong.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, that was the solution :D